# filebeat no conecta con elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, log, red

Tengo una MV en debian 11 con ELK y kibana en la misma maquina y tengo otra maquina con filebeat para enviar inputs a la que tiene ELK pero me sale este error

```
{"log.level":"error","@timestamp":"2023-02-13T13:59:14.502+0100","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1071},"message":"Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at https://192.168.194.142:9200: Get \"https://192.168.194.142:9200\": Service Unavailable]","service.name":"filebeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at https://192.168.194.142:9200: Get "https://192.168.194.142:9200": Service Unavailable]
```

Tengo la seguridad básica con ususario y contraseña.
ejecuto filebeat test config -e y no da errores
ejecuto fileebat setup -e y me pone el error que menciono al principio...
2 he intentado modificar configuraciones y nada
3 el codigo que necesiteis seria este, el de filebeat.yml

```
142 # ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
143 output.elasticsearch:
144   # Array of hosts to connect to.
145   hosts: ["https://192.168.194.142:9200"]
146   #ssl.verification_mode:none
147
148   # Protocol - either `http` (default) or `https`.
149   #  protocol: "https"
150
151   # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
152   #api_key: "id:api_key"
153   username: "filebeat_user"
154   password: "filebeat."
155   #password: "GyPUwo+SF*m4-XfrX=W="
156   #ssl:
157   #  enabled: false
158   #  ca_trusted_fingerprint: "FA:A0:38:7F:C6:96:71:4F:8D:12:7C:8C:8C:67:81:2C:40:07:99:B6:17:1>
159
# =================================== Kibana ===================================
107
108 # Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
109 # This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
110 setup.kibana:
111
112   # Kibana Host
113   # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
114   # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
115   # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
116   host: "https://192.168.194.142:5601/"
117   #ssl.verification_mode: none
118   username: "my_kibana_user"
119   password: "kibana."
120   # Kibana Space ID
121   # ID of the Kibana Space into which the dashboards should be loaded. By default,
122   # the Default Space will be used.
123   #space.id:
```

¿alguna idea?

Un saludo y gracias por contestar...

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias Ochoa por contestar y a christian. Mi problema es que instalo elasticsearch y kibana en la misma maquina y todo bien, después instalo filebeat en otra maquina y lo configuro pero me sale un mensaje de error que dice que no se puede conectar a elasticsearch, hay un video de tutorial que he seguido y está clavado, he desactivado la autenticación ssl con ssl_verify_mode: none pero nada no se quiere conectar... Un saludo.

Comment: Tengo que configurar el proxy que tengo... ¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo? menudo telar es esto de ELK.